# Azure Function running twice

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

We have a Azure Function which processes a huge file.
We noticed that it is running second time on its own.

Is there any configuration\setting where  we can disable this behavior ?

Comment: Its triggered by a BlobTrigger??

Comment: no its http triggered ...

Comment: Is your problem similar to this [post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1431) ? Only triggered once but get two logs.

Comment: no .. i am splitting a file .. it is getting split twice too ..

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure in Function setting **`RunOnStartup`** to **`false`**.

Comment: it is set to false  already ..it is running twice after http trigger hit ..